# Qt 5 configuration

Tags: kde, configuration, qt, kde4, qt5

I have a problem setting Qt5 apps correctly on my computer.
I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with KDE4, I have configured the look in the KDE system settings and that look is used in every qt4 apps and gtk apps, but not in qt5 apps. 
The most annoying think is that I use double click to activate item, but in qt5 apps this is ignored and items are activated with single click.

Does anybody know how can I change the default Qt5 setting?
I have tried deleting my .kde folder, moving it to .kde4, tried different configurations in KDE system settings, tried to find qtconfig for Qt5 (which seems not to exist anymore) and even installed daily build of KF5 and used the KDE5 system setting where I set theme, coloring and mouse behaviour and even that was ignored in Qt5 apps.

I know that Qt5 will tried to use the system settings automatically - that is the reason why there is no qtconfig, but it just not working at all.

So here I'm asking for anybody help on this topic or at least some info how to configure Qt properly or to say it better: how to configure qt5 at least somehow.

Also I'm using the ubuntu's QT5.2.1 but I also installed QT5.3 from Qt website but the behaviour is the same in both version

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately [Qt5 designers removed the package](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/45612/) equivalent of `qt4-qtconfig` in Qt4.
[They leaved as well quite a big bug behind](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-32254) as Qt5 ignores the font-config of the system.

There is then no way around to "correct" the font used by Qt5.

To get some applications behave like the others on my desktop I had to recompile them with Qt4 whenever possible.

Thus bug is now reported as closed in Qt5 version 5.4 on Aug. 20, 2014 ...

However, at this moment there is no Debian nor Ubuntu packages available from Qt5 version 5.4, even in the [“Canonical Qt5 Edgers” team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-qt5-edgers).

Although I found a [Qt5 Configuration Tool](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/Qt5+Configuration+Tool?content=168066) on http://qt-apps.org website, still this app requires Qt5 version 5.4.0.

I hope Ubuntu will backport this version to Trusty 14.04 LTS one day ...

Answer (score 1):

**Qt5 style**

You could edit the Qt application look by using the Style sheets.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qapplication.html#QApplication

```
All Qt programs automatically support the following command line options:
-style= style, sets the application GUI style. Possible values depend on your system configuration. If you compiled Qt with additional styles or have additional styles as plugins these will be available to the -style command line option. You can also set the style for all Qt applications by setting the QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE environment variable.
-style style, is the same as listed above.
-stylesheet= stylesheet, sets the application styleSheet. The value must be a path to a file that contains the Style Sheet.

Note: Relative URLs in the Style Sheet file are relative to the Style Sheet file's path.
-stylesheet stylesheet, is the same as listed above.
-widgetcount, prints debug message at the end about number of widgets left undestroyed and maximum number of widgets existed at the same time
-reverse, sets the application's layout direction to Qt::RightToLeft
-qmljsdebugger=, activates the QML/JS debugger with a specified port. The value must be of format port:1234[,block], where block is optional and will make the application wait until a debugger connects to it.
```

More of the Style sheets:

- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet.html
- http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html

**QtCurve**

The latest QtCurve /1, 2/ has widget style for applications based on the Qt 5.x.

The QMPlay2 (Qt5) /3/ with the native Qt5 and the QtCurve widget styles:

[image]

**Links**

1. https://github.com/QtCurve/qtcurve
2. https://projects.kde.org/projects/playground/base/qtcurve
3. http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php/QMPlay2?content=153339